# how to access the url inside .success of the $http.get method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following controller

```
var app = angular.module('callapp', []);
app.controller('eController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.urlString = []; //this is filled with values

    for( var i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        var currentURL = $scope.urlString[i];
        $http.get(currentURL)
        .success( function(response) {
            //how do I access currentURL here?
            $log.info(this.currURL) //this is printing "undefined"
        });
    }
```

The urls are generated dynamically, and I have to get data from these urls. The urls are generated before the for loop executes (and the url requests are asynchronous).

I tried $.ajax(currentURL) instead of $http.get method, but I got the same result - "undefined".

Is there any way I can access the currentURL and the current value of 'i' inside the .success(function ())?

Comment: when $.ajax(currentURL) is used, note that you have to use "this.url" to access the currentURL. It does not work if you use "this.currentURL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentUrl` is easily accessible, and since you're making AJAX requests inside a for loop, you will always get `i` to be the last `index` value because the renderer will print the value when the AJAX req gives `200` which will take some time and within that time `for` loop would have executed, so always the last index value will be there in `i`. For this, you have to use [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

For the purpose of Demo, I'm using a Fake Online REST API - http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

**RUNNING DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/djPMu4UH9t9BeGwBcUMI**

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="callapp" ng-controller="eController">
</body>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('callapp', []);
app.controller('eController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.baseUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
    $scope.urlString = [
      $scope.baseUrl + '1',
      $scope.baseUrl +'2',
      $scope.baseUrl + '3'
    ]; //this is filled with values


    for( var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
       (function(index) {
        var currentURL = $scope.urlString[i];
        $http.get(currentURL)
        .success( function(response) {
            $log.info(index+1, currentURL);
        });
      })(i);
    }
});

app.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$log'];
```

Comment: the solution is working perfectly, but i didn't get why >  app.$inject < is used explicitly

Comment: To allow the minifiers to rename the function parameters and still be able to inject the right services, the function needs to be annotated with the $inject property. The $inject property is an array of service names to inject. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

You can register an HttpInterceptor. In the interceptor it's possible to catch/handle all requests.

More info at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
  return {
     // optional method
     'request': function(config) {
       // This is your URL:
       console.log(config.url);
       return config;
     },
  };
});
```

Don't forget to register the httpInterceptor like this:
`$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');`

Answer (score 0):

store value in $scope variable because this.currUrl is undefined

```
 var app = angular.module('callapp', []);
    app.controller('eController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
        $scope.urlString = []; //this is filled with values

        for( var i=0; i<3; ++i)
        {
            $scope.currentURL = $scope.urlString[i];
            $http.get($scope.currentURL)
            .success( function(response) {
                //how do I access currentURL here?

            });
 $log.info($scope.currentURL);
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the calls are asynchronous and if the back-end data return is slow, the for loop finishes executing. So $scope.currentURL is set to $scope.urlString[2] in all the three .success(function()) callbacks

Comment: I have edited the answer now if calls are aysnc then also it will give values

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop use angular forEach .For more information on angularForeach visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control

```
var app = angular.module('callapp', []);
app.controller('eController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
$scope.baseUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
$scope.urlString = [$scope.baseUrl + '1', $scope.baseUrl +'2',$scope.baseUrl + '3']; //this is filled with values

angular.forEach($scope.urlString,function(value,key){

    $http.get(value)
    .success( function(response) {
        $log.info(value) 
    });
}    
});

app.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$log'];
```